# Create a counter in game android

Tags: android, multithreading, view, canvas

I am doing a game .I want creat a counter .It begin from 200 and then 1s reduced about 0 .It my code :

```
public class GameView extends View{

private int count = 200;
private TimeCountThread timeCountThread;

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    timeCountThread = new TimeCountThread();
            timeCountThread.start();
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("Time :"+count, 10, 35, paint);
}

public class TimeCountThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while(count > 0){
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                count--;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        int x1=(int) event.getX();
        int y1=(int) event.getY();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x1 = "+x1+", y1 ="+y1,1).show();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Why the counter don't activity .Please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I want creat a counter .It begin from 200 and then 1s reduced about 0

You can achieve it by [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a handler with a runnable inside of it. Such as:

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        count--;
        if(count > 0) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }              
    }
};
if(count > 0) {
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

where your

```
timeCountThread = new TimeCountThread();
        timeCountThread.start();
```

is. Another problem might be that your count is private, but I don't think that that will make that big of a difference.